# best practice for placing descriptions and landing pages

Tags: best-practice

this is probably a question for the magento forums directly, but as they are such a spam-fest.. I'll try here :)

I want to put at the top of each product category a large splash image and description etc (which I've done) and it all looks and works fine.

However, the ultimo theme which I'm using looks to encourage the use of blocks for content > and enabling those as needed in each category.

Personally, its much quicker and easier for me to just edit the categories as I go. **My question is though..** which is really the best practice, and why? The one thing that comes to mind is, if I kill a category by mistake - the landing page would still exist in a block > so maybe safer? Any other reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a right answer here. It's just about choosing your weapon.
The use of blocks is a bit more flexible. It allows you to insert widgets in there, enable/disable them, use the same block for different categories. And the list can go on (I'm just out of ideas for the moment).

If you just want to add a simple image and a simple text for each category there is no need to get the static blocks involved. You can easily use track of which is which.

So I guess the best practice is the the one that works for you. You have to weigh the advantages and disadvantages of each approach and see what fits best with your business.

Comment: ok, great. I just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing some obvious "Oh My God you shouldn't do that!!" type response :)